# Matlab : how to read a constant width text file and turn it into a matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, text-files

i have a ASCII text file each row has format

```
------------------------------
Variable   Columns   Type
------------------------------
ID            1-11   Character
YEAR         12-15   Integer
MONTH        16-17   Integer
ELEMENT      18-21   Character
VALUE1       22-26   Integer
MFLAG1       27-27   Character
QFLAG1       28-28   Character
SFLAG1       29-29   Character
VALUE2       30-34   Integer
MFLAG2       35-35   Character
QFLAG2       36-36   Character
SFLAG2       37-37   Character
  .           .          .
  .           .          .
  .           .          .
VALUE31    262-266   Integer
MFLAG31    267-267   Character
QFLAG31    268-268   Character
SFLAG31    269-269   Character
------------------------------
```

i only need variables  "year"  "month"  "element"  and "valuei" i = 1,2,...,31 (there are 31 values in each row)

parameters (like MFLAGi) can have a character in their place or white-space .
also value might not fill all of it's space with numbers so there can be space.

two sample lines from my text file

```
USC00190736189301TMAX   33  6  117  6    0 I6  -89  6  -28  6  -83  6  -67  6  -67  6  -28  6   -6  6 -139  6 -111  6 -117  6  -89  6 -106  6 -111  6 -106  6 -106  6  -39  6  -78  6  -61  6  -33  6   -6  6    6  6   39  6   28  6    6  6  -61  6   61  6   56  6    0  6
USC00190736189301TMIN  -56  6   11 I6 -106  6 -161  6 -106  6 -133  6 -144  6 -117  6 -161  6 -156  6 -206  6 -183  6 -161  6 -161  6 -139  6 -178  6 -189  6 -161  6 -133  6 -150  6 -156  6 -156  6 -100  6  -50  6  -39  6  -67  6  -78  6 -111  6  -94  6  -33  6  -50  6
```

for example in line 1 value1 has only used 2 out of it's 5 spaces (`'   33'`)
and both MFLAG1 and QFLAG1 are white-space .

i want to put "year"  "month"  "element"  and "valuei" in a matrix and depending on the "element" value choose some of the rows and make my final matrix how can i do that ?

what i have thought of :

```
%open file
fid = fopen('myt.txt')

% read from file 
%'whitespace','' do not overlook white spaces in counting 
C  = textscan(fid , formatspec ,'whitespace','')
```

i have two problems with this:

1. the formatspec i think should be

   ```
   '%*11c    %4d    %2d    %4c          %5d       %*3c'
   ignore   year   month  element      valuei    ignore
                                       ------------------
                                    repeat this part 31 times
   ```

how can i repeat that part 31 times and concat all the parts together ?

2. i end up having a cell array C since "element" is a string i can't change it into a matrix. apparently C is column by column and each column is a whole string . then how can i access the read data row by row to select the rows i need (according to the value of "element") ?

am I using the wrong method to do what i want ? what should i do ?

Comment: In case you do not have any delimiter you probably have to fall back on `fgetl` + regexp I think. However by looking at your file sample it does not look exactly as what you have described above. It rather looks to be tab delimited. In that case `textscan` with proper typespec should work.

Comment: no the text is not tab separated . it's fixed width text file . the column number determines the start and end of each field .

Comment: and i was able to read a more simple fixed width text file as i mentioned above with textscan . but in this case i faced the two problems i said .

Comment: Your sample data doesn't fit your description of it, it has more like 60 columns.

Comment: @Carlos There are 31 values whose length is 8 characters long and the row information is 21 characters. That equals 269, which is the length of each of his rows. Read the problem description...

Comment: @excaza ah, you're right. got confused by '31 values in each row'.

Answer (score 0):

for (1), you can use repmat:

```
idspec = ['%*11c    %4d    %2d    %4c '];
valuespec = repmat('%5d %*3c',[1 31]);
filespec = [idspec valuespec];
```

(or something similar)

for (2), I can see a few options:

a) You could read the file twice, once ignoring the character column, and using the 'collectoutput' option, so that C would basically contain a matrix. You can read again by ignoring everything but ELEMENT, so that C would have the remaining info.

b) Using 'collectoutput', you'd have C with the year a month, then the ELEMENT, and then the rest.